# Optimizing Java worker speed-wise

Tags: java

I've got a Java worker that handles a lot of data. It waits on a Redis queue in main() and then calls different functions to handle the data depending on type.

I've got two questions on optimizing the code:

1. Would it be better to have private static class variables and use them to send data to methods instead of using function arguments?
2. Would it speed up execution time if variables used in these often-called methods would be private static on class instead of declared always over again when entering the method?

Thanks

Comment: Regardless of what you do, make sure you get performance metrics (both synthetic and real world) before you make the change, and then after. Otherwise you will have no idea if you've helped, or hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about speed, but `static` variables will help you mostly memory-wise.

**If you are creating multiple instante variables (non-`static` fields) and thinking of changing to into a `static` one:**

> When multiple instances of a class need access to a particular object in a variable local to those instances (instance variable), it is better to make that variable a `static` variable rather than have each instance hold a separate reference. This reduces the **space** taken by each object (one less instance variable) and can also reduce the number of objects created if each instance creates a separate object to populate that instance variable. (Quoted from [Java Performance Tuning](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html) book.)

**If you are not creating instance variables, but just passing a variable along in parameters:**

Performance-wise, there should be no difference. As a all method parameters in Java are passed value-by-reference, meaning that the actual variable is not copied over an over: only its address (pointer - a reference to the variable) is copied into the parameter of the called method.

In any case, `static` fields can compromise your code's readability (it can make them so much harder to maintain). If you really need a `static` behaviour, please also consider using a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

**Bottom line is:**

Seems to me your scenario is: You are just passing variables along (an not having instance variables).

I advise you to keep it that way. If you change it, there will be near-zero (if any) performance gain by using static fields -- on the other hand, your code will be much harder to maintain/understand/debug.